# Local function template in cpp file: should I make it static?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```cpp
// CPP file

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
}

// Use the template only in this CPP as foo<int>, foo<char>, etc.
```

Suppose I have CPP file and there I have a template function `foo` for internal usage inside this CPP file only. Do I understand right that if I don't put the template into anonymous namespace or don't make it `static`, ***its instantiations*** used/created in this CPP file (e.g. `foo<int>{}`, `foo<char>{}`, etc.) will have external linkage, i.e. will be seen outside. So is it true, that I better have the template static, as shown below or have it in anonymous namespace?

```cpp
// CPP file

template<typename T>
static void foo()
{
}
```

Comment: I'd do both the namespace and the qualifier. You want the template to have internal linkage too. Aa for the instantiations... whether it be intentional or a bug (in either the compiler or standard) redundancy isn't harmful.

Comment: Yes, you should. Otherwise if you have >1 TU with templates with the same names, they might get merged in a bad way.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's why the One Definition Rule exists.

Comment: Your thinking right. The functions that are created by instantiating template `Foo` are regular functions, not templates. Unless you place them in an anonymous namespace, or else declare them with static linkage, they will be visible to the linker. It's an opt-out deal. If and when you switch to modules, you will probably appreciate the opt-in approach modules take towards linkage. If you do not positively export a name from a module, it remains internal to the module. No anonymous namespace needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole function template has external linkage by default. Specializations/instantiations do not have any separate linkage attribute. Since `foo` is however a template it is however allowed to have multiple definitions in multiple translation units nonetheless, but only as long as they are *exactly* identical.

If you don't give it internal linkage explicitly and another translation unit happens to define another function template of the signature and name

```
template<typename T>
void foo();
```

with a different definition, then your program will violate the one-definition rule and have undefined behavior.

So yes, it must be declared `static` or in an anonymous namespace, if that is (possibly) going to be the case.

Comment: I think **must** is a little strong.  However it would be highly recommended.

Comment: @MarkRansom It is a must assuming there exists a conflicting definition in another translation unit. I clarified that in my answer.

Comment: That's a big assumption.  Most of the time there won't be a conflicting definition and you'll be Ok.  The way you had it worded sounded like it would be immediately undefined behavior.  Appreciate the edit.